# Overload function with parameters of same type but different ranges

Tags: swift

Is it possible to overload a function with the same parameter types but different ranges? I’m trying to implement a subscript extension for `Array` for negative indices, so that if `let a = [3, 1, 4]`, `a[-1] == 4`, `a[-2] == 1`, etc. Swift’s `Array` already has a subscript function, so I don’t want to replace it, but create an overloaded function just for negative integers. Is this any way of doing this? Thanks.

Comment: This answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/29731961/1187415 shows how to "overload" the subscript by defining a custom type that wraps the index.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not. Functions signature is based on parameter count and parameter types. That is not possible because the compiler wouldn't know what to do if some positive number is passed. It can not check for it's value before it calls a function.